# Angular2 or React or any other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, reactjs, vue.js

I've worked on multiple angular 1 projects and I totally loved it . We have few projects in the pipeline for which I need to provide recommendations for JavaScript frontend libraries/ frameworks . Since angular 1 is fading and angular 2 is a total redesign with considerable amount of bad reviews is it a good idea to move to angular 2 ( I've read in some articles recently that angular 4 is in horizon) . I've used a little bit of react as well but for some reason didn't really liked JSX. Saying that React is also one of our options . Lately I've been listening a lot about vue.js ( not really sure if we are going to use it)

If you can provide some insights in selecting one framework over the other that would be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular, React and vue.js are all very mature libraries/frameworks. I would recommend you and anybody with the same question to try all of them. Doing a simple TODO list app might be enough for anybody to see if the like a library/framework or not. If you didn't really like JSX, give a try to vue.js and choose the one you feel more confident with.

Also, posting this kind of question here might not be the best choice. I would suggest you to ask them on a website like [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-angular-vs-react)

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations? - Angular!

Why?
I am have been using angular for about 3 years and still counting. I have found very well defined answers to my queries. I don't like their documentation. Some are very brief and some very detailed that finding [small] one, is hard. There are 100s of advantages i can give for Angular-why? - because i have used. There are many libraries that are evolving for the use of angular. And yes, angular is constantly evolving, and am excited about Angular4.

why not React? - I have used it too, but i did not like it. And the preferences and solutions to the problems are hard to find compared with Angular.

As you already have learnt and practiced angular, angular2 would not be a problem nor i think angular4 should either. But if you take on React, you will probably divert your way out Angular.

Disclaimer: This is completely personal approach and review.